Were Levites allowed to enter the Holy Place or was it only for priests?
The Bible shows that Aaron and his sons were chosen from the rest of the sons of Levi to officiate as priests, and these "other" Levites had secondary functions in religious service. There is, however, something I can't see clearly yet: Priests (Aaron's sons) would indeed enter the Court and the Holy Place, but would other Levites also enter the Holy Place?
(Of course, not in the Holy of Holies, for that would be only once a year, only the High Priest, and therefore a son of Aaron.)
Numbers 18:4 made it more complex, for it says that Levites were to "keep the charge of the Tent of Meeting, whatsoever the service of the Tent may be," and the following passages don't help either. Especially verse 7, where it states "thou [Aaron] and thy sons with thee shall keep your priesthood in everything that pertaineth to the altar, and to that within the veil," this veil is the veil of the Holy of Holies, suggesting that the "other" Levites could also work inside the Holy Place, and not only the outer court.
Other passages, such as Numbers chapter 4, suggest that Levites wouldn't enter the Holy Place etc.
So: Levites could enter the Holy Place or not?

As for Numbers 18:3 (:4 in your question), the Sforno says: ושמרו משמרתך ומשמרת האהל, the Levites are to guard the Holy of Holies (structure) which in itself is your domain; they are also to guard all the other sacred locations outside the Holy of Holies.

"It also seems that that which Maimonides, may his memory be blessed, said that it is elucidated in Joshua is from this verse, but it is not a clear elucidation at all, as we have said. And that which is stated in I Kings 8:1, “And the Kohanim brought the Ark of the Covenant of the Lord to its place, to the sanctuary, to the Holy of Holies” should also not be difficult in your eyes. It is because the Levites were not permitted to enter the Holy of Holies that only the Kohanim brought it in." - Sefer HaChinuch 379:3.

I think only the priests could enter certain areas.

I see, @Shmuel and thank you, but what about the Holy Place (the first part of the tent)? In the Holy of Holies they wouldn't enter indeed, but I can't see it clear whether they entered the Holy Place or not.

The Levites were considered Israel in regards to entering the Court of Kohanim, as Mishnayot in Keilim 1.8-9 state: 'Ezras Kohanim - The Court of the Priests (1) is holier, for Israelites may not enter it except when they are required to do so: for laying on of the hands, slaying or waving. The areas beyond the Altar had further restrictions and even some kohanim could not enter there, certainly ulam and the Holy.
The Cortyard of the Mishkan (2) was smaller, but had the same restrictions as the inner Court the Temple had later.
In the desert, the entrance to Mishkan was restricted to Aharon and his sons. Moshe could also enter to receive prophecy inside the Ohel Moed - Tent of the Meeting (Holy of Holies). However, we can also see that technically, G-d could call anybody inside the Tent of the Meeting, as we see in the story of Miriam and Aharon in Bamidbar 12:4 (Miriam was a wife of Calev - a member of the tribe of Yehuda).
On the other hand, mishna Middos 2:6, in the Temple Courtyard Leviim had a special chamber underneath 'Ezras Israel where they kept their instruments.

(1) the area between the gates of Nikanor and the outer altar was divided into 2 parts: Court of Israel and Court of the Priests. In Hebrew 'Ezras Israel and 'Ezras Kohanim. The size of the court of Israel was 135 cubits by 11 cubits and the same size for the court of the Priests. There were also 3 steps in between them, so that the court of the priests was 2.5 cubits higher. See Mishna Middos 2.6. The Mishkan did not have steps and it was one level.
(2) the dimensions of the Courtyard of the Mishkan


Thank you, Y DJ. What is meant by "Court of the Priests?"

@jean-luc the area between the gates of Nikanor and the outer altar was divided into 2 parts: Court of Israel and Court of the Priests. In Hebrew 'Ezras Israel and 'Ezras Kohanim. The size of the court of Israel was 135 cubits by 11 cubits and the same size for the court of the Priests. There were also 3 steps in between them, so that the court of the priests was 2.5 cubits higher. See Mishna Middos 2.6 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Middot.2.6?vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi

Oh, I see. But I meant the wilderness Mishkan. It was divided in two parts, the Holy and the Most Holy Place. Could Levites enter it?

@jean-luc Yes. The Mishkan had the same form as the Temple, although smaller. You are talking about Ohel Moed which was located inside the Mishkan in the area beyond the outer Altar. Only kohanim who did the service were allowed inside, i.e. Aharon and his two sons. Also Moshe was allowed inside to receive the prophecy. He was a Levi, but an exception to the rule. In the Temple Ohel Moed - The Tent of the Meeting - was replaced by the Heikhal.

Oh, thanks. Yes, indeed. I notice you said, "exception to the rule," so "other" Levites (apart from Aaron, his sons, and Moses) weren't allowed to enter it, right? Upon reading some rabbis commenting various verses, it seems clear to me that Levites are one "clan" and Kohanim another "clan." Although both are Levites, only Moses, Aaron and his seed (the Kohanim) could enter the Tent of Meeting, the Ohel Moed, as you said.

@jean-luc correct. Moses received his prophecy there after it was built, and that was why he was allowed in.
